# Number of triangles having particular area

Tags: calculus, geometry

If $g:R\to \ N\cup\big\{0\big\}$ and $g(x)=n$,
where $x$ represents the area of triangle joining the two fixed points and a variable point $R(p,q)$such that $\angle PRQ=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $n$ represents the number of such triangles.Then which of the following is/are true

(A)$g(5)=4$

(B)$g(7)=0$

(C)$g(6.25)=2$

(D)$g(9)=1$

In my attempt,I think all these triangles are inside a semi circle and PQ is diameter and R is on the circumference because $\angle PRQ=\frac{\pi}{2}$.But i could not judge right answer.How can i reach to the answers.One or more than one options are correct.

Comment: The distance $PQ$ is needed.

Comment: distance PQ is not given in the question,sir.

Comment: which coordinates has $P,Q$?

Answer (score 1):

Distance $PQ$ is needed to give complete answers, but here is an idea to solve the problem. Call $d=PQ$. We want to know the number of solutions of this system:

$$\begin{cases}a^2+b^2=d^2\\ab=2x\end{cases}$$

If we add and substract the first equation and the double of the second one, we get
$$\begin{cases}(a+b)^2=d^2+4x\\(a-b)^2=d^2-4x\end{cases}$$

This system has two solutions when $0<4x<d^2$, one solution if $4x=d^2$ and has no solutions if $4x>d^2$.